# Recreate highly-distorted italic letters

Tags: font-identification

Any idea what this 'WHITE' text could be?

[image: 1]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's distorted piece of text with some quite light serif font. An example of distortion (not exact, only resembling) with font Wicker SF:

[image]

1. The starting point as text
2. The text is outlined (=converted to paths) and ungrouped. Top side nodes are moved upwards with the node editing tool (=direct selection tool in Illustrator), the bottom side nodes are moved downwards. One can select a bunch of nodes and move them by clicking arrow keys for repeatable movements. Stretching vertically is nor done by scaling because it would make serifs and horizontal lines thicker.
3. The letter outlines are shifted further from each other. The same can be got by increasing letter spacing or by inserting spaces before outlining the text.
4. Letter V is duplicated
5. Horizontal skew is added. It's also called slanting or fake italic if it's applied to text.

In questioner's image there's also some warping (or envelope distortion in Illustrator). It's inserted to follow (very coarsely) the surface of the cloth.

Comment: you're the GOAT‼️ tysm ♡